Why does subtracting a child row from the parent row return all, including irrelevant, invoice numbers while dividing returns only relevant invoices?
DIVIDE([Invoice $] , CALCULATE([Invoice $], REMOVEFILTERS(Invoices[Invoice])))

Correctly displays only relevant invoice numbers with percent of grand total value

[Invoice $] - CALCULATE([Invoice $], REMOVEFILTERS(Invoices[Invoice]))

Returns all invoice numbers even if they do not have an [Invoice $] value.

I tried the dax measure:
[Invoice $] - CALCULATE([Invoice $], REMOVEFILTERS(Invoices[Invoice]))

How can I efficiently only return invoice numbers with an invoice $ value?

Can you share a .pbix with the issue?

It works as expected in the simple pbix i was building out to share with you. It only returns the invoice numbers for the given location hierarchy. I'm not sure why mine is returning all invoice numbers for all locations.

Next finding: It appears to be an issue with my data model. Applying filters from my Locations dimension table causes the issue.
